# UI-Grid select filter that returns all but one type

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

I have a ui-grid and one of my columns is a field that can be filtered using a select option. I'll call it 'colour' for this example. Here is the column def:

```
columnDefs: [
    {
        field: 'colour',
        cellTemplate: 'colour.cellTemplate.html',
        filter: {
            selectOptions: ['orange', 'blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'purple'].map(c =>({value:c, label:c})),
            type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT
        }
    }
]
```

Now this filters my grid by colour and works well. However I would like to add a field called something like `not blue` which would then return every row which has a colour that isn't blue. How would I implement this? If I just add an option called `not blue` then it will just return every field which has a colour value of `not blue` which would be none of them. Any ideas?

Disclaimer: I'm quite new to UI-grid and I tried to read the docs to find some help on this but couldn't manage it, so sorry if I'm missing something obvious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. There's a param called condition which can be implemented like so:

```
columnDefs: [
    {
        field: 'colour',
        cellTemplate: 'colour.cellTemplate.html',
        filter: {
            selectOptions: ['orange', 'blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'purple', 'not blue'].map(c =>({value:c, label:c})),
            type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT,
            condition: (filter, cellValue) => {
                if (filter === 'not blue') {
                    return cellValue !== 'blue';
                }
                return cellValue === filter;
            }
        }
    }
]
```